# appended div was not placing a correct location

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/2/

here is my code

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;width:200px;height:300px;border: 2px solid red;">
      <div id="container1" style="position:relative;margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;">           
      </div>
    <div id="container2" style="position:relative;margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid green;">
    </div> 
</div>
```

container2 position is same as container1 position but container2 was appended below container1 i mean it was displayed under container1. how to resolve this. i need to append the same location. with out change the position. resolve pls

Comment: use float:left in both container1 and container2

Comment: please run the code... it's not working

Comment: Instead of `position:relative` you need to give `position:absolute` for inner divs for the same position

Comment: if you want it side by side use http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/4/ and if you want them bothe on axact same postion use http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/5/

Comment: if i set absolute it's need to place based on document... i.e top value 30 append based on parent div but need to append based on document

Comment: can you share code for document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code, try this out

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;width:200px;height:300px;border: 2px solid red;">
      <div id="container1" style="float:left;margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;">           
      </div>
    <div id="container2" style="position:relative;margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid green;">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Relative to Parent***

Use `position:absolute` on both child `containers` and keep `position:relative` on parent.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/3/

***Relative to Document***

- Use `position:absolute` on both child `containers`.
- Remove`position:relative` on parent.
- Use `top` and `left` instead of `margin-top` and `margin-left`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/7/

If the parent has to be relative, consider removing the children outside the parent.

If you want to control which is on top use `z-index`.

Comment: if i set absolute it's need to place based on document... i.e top value 30 append based on parent div but need to append based on document
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712148/relative-absolute-positioning

Comment: @AkbarBasha you want the position based on document or parent div?  If it's based on the document, remove `position:relative` from the parent container.

Comment: @AkbarBasha If you're trying to position the absolute ones based on document, you need to use `top` and `left` instead of `margins`. http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/7/

Answer (score 0):

Add float left to both container1 and container2 divs.

[js fiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/6/
```