# relative + absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnk8qup/

My code:

```
   <div id="container" style="position:relative;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;width:200px;height:300px;border: 2px solid red;">
          <div id="container1" style="position:absolute;margin-top:130px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;">           
          </div>   
    </div>
```

The `container` (parent div) position is relative `container1` (child) position is absolute. I set the `container2` top location as `130px`, it can be calculated from `container` (parent div) top position but I need to show `130px` from document position. How to resolve with out changing positioning?

Comment: " i set the container2 top location as 130" where is container2, do you mean container1?

Comment: You can just subtract container's `top` value from container1's `top` value (you'll get 80): http://jsfiddle.net/kwnk8qup/2/

Comment: Etash yes container 1

Comment: It's a best practice to put your CSS code into a external file (called by the .html file), not into the HTML tags (excuse me for my english)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question, but you could just move `#container1` outside of the `#container` so it would be relative to `<body>`-element instead of `#container`-element.

```
<body>
<div id="container" style="position:relative;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;width:200px;height:300px;border: 2px solid red;"></div>  
<div id="container1" style="position:absolute;margin-top:130px;margin-left:30px;width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;"></div>   
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q29ey2qt/

Answer (score 0):

Try Margin-top: -50px for the container1 and top:130px
http://jsfiddle.net/30owkpv7/

### Css

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  }
#container1 {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-50px; /*you need 130 from body (-50) of container */
  top:130px; /*top from body*/
  margin-left:30px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;"
}
```

### HTML

`<div id="container">
      <div id="container1">  </div>

   </div>`